# How to set a jinja2 variable a value from another variable

Tags: python, django, django-forms, jinja2

In `{% set form.username = user.get_username %}` I want to make *form.username* equal to the user's username, so when the form is sent, I know who sent it. However, it raises the error: "*Did you forget to register or load this tag?*"

If I replace this line with `{{forms.username}}` it works, but it makes necessary for the user to fill the form himself, with whatever he wants, allowing him to submit a file with a username that is not his.

**file.html** (is included in the home.html):

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{% set form.username = user.get_username %}
{{ form.file }}
<button type="submit">Upload</button>
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

from data.models import UserData
from data.forms import UserDataForm

def model_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserDataForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    else:
        form = UserDataForm()
    return render(request, 'data/ranking_index.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models

class UserData(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='userdata/')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms

from data.models import UserData

class UserDataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserData
        fields = ('username', 'file', )
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't included `user` when rendering the template. So as a result jinja2 fails to find the value for `user`. I suggest the following.

```
return render(request, '<your template>', {
    'form': form
    'user': user
})
```

You need to create this `user` object in the same function or import from somewhere else its created. Hope this helps!